# Understanding why git-tf sometimes fails on pull --deep --rebase

Tags: git-tf

Background: I've just started using git-tf after being extremely frustrated with the wait times pulling down a TFS project with 50+ branches (and so many other reasons). Not a git user previously, so I'm learning all the commands and functionality as I go.

I do all of my development work in local branches, then when I'm ready to push to TFS, I swap back to master and do **git tf pull --deep --rebase**. Most of the time this works flawlessly - everything is pulled down, files are updated, life is good. Recently though, it has been occasionally failing with the following messages:

```
Fetching and merging changes in $/TFS/repo at latest changeset: 100%, done

All files were fetched to commit 59ad2a4. The rebase operation was aborted with 
the following failures:

Project.Subproject/Folder/SomeRandomFile.sql : the file has uncommitted changes in the 
working folder
```

Prior to running pull, git status confirmed I had zero changes in master. After this, git status still confirms I have no modified files.

At this point I can (and have been) merging '59ad2a4' or whatever it is into master, which works as expected and I go back to work. Just curious what's actually going on here, if there's something I'm doing wrong or not understanding, since this seems to happen randomly.

Comment: I'm surprised `git-tf` is faster than a native client...  it really should be the opposite.  In any case, this is interesting.   What is your `core.autocrlf` setting?  See also: http://gittf.codeplex.com/discussions/394682

Comment: It's faster because TFS is so clunky; branches are physically separate folders, so when you switch them in VS you're physically changing solution files, versus updating files based on their changesets - the former workflow is very annoying! My core.autocrlf setting is true, as of a few days ago when we noticed we were breaking line endings for the rest of the TFS developers, so all the git folks changed it to true, which fixed said issues. Come to think of it, these issues started shortly after setting it true.

Comment: I thought you meant that just doing a get latest was faster in git-tf than with TFS.  If it's faster for your workflow, then that's cool.